# Scala: Get type name without runtime reflection and without type instance

Tags: scala, macros, metaprogramming

I'd like to get the name of a type, as a String, without runtime reflection.

Using macros, and with an instance of the type, I can do it like this:

```scala
def typeNameFromInstance[A](instance: A): String = 
  macro typeNameFromInstanceImplementation[A]

def typeNameFromInstanceImplementation[A](
  c: Context)(
    instance: c.Expr[A]): c.Expr[String] = {
  import c.universe._

  val name = instance.actualType.toString
  c.Expr[String](Literal(Constant(name)))
}
```

How can I do this without an instance of the type? I'd like a function signature like:

```or-tag-here
def typeName[A]: String
```

I can't use ClassTags because they don't provide the full type name, just the erased type. I also apparently can't use TypeTags because of [thread safety issues](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/thread-safety.html).

EDIT: It appears this isn't possible in full generality (eg nested function calls). The accepted answer below states this in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access tree that represents macro application: `c.macroApplication`

```
def typeName[T]: String = macro typeName_impl[T]

def typeName_impl[T](c: Context): c.Expr[String] = {
  import c.universe._

  val TypeApply(_, List(typeTree)) = c.macroApplication
  c.literal(typeTree.toString())
}
```

**EDIT:**

Another way to get the same, but maybe a little nicer:

```
def typeName[T]: String = macro typeName_impl[T]

def typeName_impl[T: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context): c.Expr[String] = {
  import c.universe._

  c.literal(weakTypeOf[T].toString())
}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't return the final static type. Suppose I define: "def printType[A] = println(typeName[A])". Then the call "printType[List[Int]]" prints "A" not "List[Int]".

Comment: If you want it to work like this, then I don't think it is possible without `TypeTag`s. Macro is expanded during compilation, so your code: `def printType[A] = println(typeName[A])` is actually translated to `def printType[A] = println("A")`. The only thing you can possibly do here is define `printType` also as a macro. Its implementation may look like this: `def printType_impl[T](c: Context): c.Expr[Unit] = c.universe.reify(println(typeName_impl[T](c).splice))`