# Scala. How to Infer generic type inside class inheritance

Tags: scala, reflection, macros

I have two classes:

```
class Base[A]{
    def doSome:A
}

class StringImpl extends Base[String]
```

How can I infer (without manifest, only reflection analysys) that generic type A inside class StringImpl is a String? (In real case Iheritance structure may be mach more complex that example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using scala runtime reflection (`isInstanceOf` doesn't work for erased types - it always returns `true`):

```
typeOf[StringImpl] <:< typeOf[Base[String]] //true 
typeOf[StringImpl] <:< typeOf[Base[Int]] //false
```

See: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.7/scala-reflect/#scala.reflect.api.Types$TypeApi

```
val tp = typeOf[StringImpl]
tp.baseType(tp.baseClasses(1)).typeArgs
res17_4: List[reflect.runtime.package.universe.Type] = List(String)
```

It allows you to access type-parameters etc for a more complicated case.

Update. for `ClassSymbol` you can use `typeSignature` method:

```
tp.typeSymbol.typeSignature

res19_5: reflect.runtime.package.universe.Type = Helper.this.Base[String] {
  def <init>(): Helper.this.StringImpl
  def doSome: String
}
```

Also, for macro (if you don't want obvious `WeakTypeTag` solution):

```
 import c.universe._
 val TypeApply(_, List(typeTree)) = c.macroApplication
 //you can analyze typeTree here
```

[Scala: Get type name without runtime reflection and without type instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15649720/scala-get-type-name-without-runtime-reflection-and-without-type-instance)

---

General answer

Generic types are erased in JVM, so no info is stored by default in runtime - it "physically" impossible to get erased type in runtime without ClassTag/TypeTag in general case (you can only explore method/member signatures in subclass if such exist). However, you can always do compile-time check, something like:

```
abstract class Base{
   type A
   def doSome:A
}

class StringImpl extends Base{
   type A = String
   def doSome:A = "aaa"

}

implicitly[StringImpl#A =:= String]
```

Comment: The direct position of the types is erased, but type declarations at the level in the declared classes remain. You can calculate the type or its lower bound if you analyze type substitutions in the chain of inheritance class by class. I used this method in java reflection, and I thought maybe there was something ready to the scala reflection or macros/toolbox API.

Comment: @RomanYurin I updated answer with `typeOf[StringImpl] <:< typeOf[Base[String]] `. Basically you can explore classes in that way

Comment: It work with explicit code in compile time, but not with reflection symbols. I had StringImpl as ClassSymbol in my task. (I develop code analisys tool)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get `doSome` method **return type** for the generic type **A** without **Manifest**(for doesn't have access to the **parent** class), like:

```
new StringImpl().getClass.getMethod("doSome").getReturnType.getSimpleName
> String
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I work in macros black box context, method is not accessible in these time, only MethodSymbol of Base.doSome with pure generic type A.